# Condense dataframe with conditions to certain columns

Tags: r

I've got a dataset that looks like this

```
df = data.frame(Site = c(rep('w',4),rep('x',5),rep('y',2),rep('z',1)),
                Parent = c(rep('W Inc.',4),rep('X Inc.',5),rep('Y Inc.',2),rep('Z Inc.',1)),
                Status = c(rep('Prospect',4),rep('Client',5),rep('Client',2),rep('Prospect',1)),
                Country = c(rep('USA',4),rep('Canada',5),rep('Mexico',2),rep('China',1)),
                ProductID = c('XP10','XP11','XP18','XP19','XP4','XP5','XP6','XP7','XP8','XP10','XP18','XP6'),
                ProductName = c('10Rockets','11Rockets','18Rockets','19Rockets','4Rockets','5Rockets','6Rockets','7Rockets','8Rockets','10Rockets','18Rockets','6Rockets'),
                ProductProvider= c('Provider A','Provider B','Provider A','Provider A',rep('Provider A',5),'Provider A','Provider B','Provider B'))
```

I'd like to condense it such that each `Site` is a unique row, and the last 3 columns are concatenated.
Also, I'd like to concatenate the last column such that if there are any repetitions, it takes only the unique values per `Site` and separates them with commas.

**My attempt**

```
library(dplyr)
output2 = df %>% group_by(Site,Parent,Status,Country) %>% 
  mutate(ProductID = paste(ProductID, collapse=",")) %>%
  mutate(ProductName = paste(ProductName, collapse=",")) %>%
  mutate(ProductProvider = unique(paste(ProductProvider, collapse=","))) %>%
  distinct()
```

I'm almost there, but the last column seems to have repetitions of `ProductProvider` which I do not want.

**Target Output**

I'm looking for a target data set like this, with the last column concatenated and free of any repetitions. Any inputs would be appreciated.

```
output = data.frame(Site = c(rep('w',1),rep('x',1),rep('y',1),rep('z',1)),
                Parent = c(rep('W Inc.',1),rep('X Inc.',1),rep('Y Inc.',1),rep('Z Inc.',1)),
                Status = c(rep('Prospect',1),rep('Client',1),rep('Client',1),rep('Prospect',1)),
                Country = c(rep('USA',1),rep('Canada',1),rep('Mexico',1),rep('China',1)),
                ProductID = c('XP10,XP11,XP18,XP19','XP4,XP5,XP6,XP7,XP8','XP10,XP18','XP6'),
                ProductName = c('10Rockets,11Rockets,18Rockets,19Rockets','4Rockets,5Rockets,6Rockets,7Rockets,8Rockets','10Rockets,18Rockets','6Rockets'),
                ProductProvider= c('Provider A,Provider B','Provider A','Provider A,Provider B','Provider B'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
result = df %>% group_by(Site, Parent, Status, Country) %>%
  summarize(across(ProductProvider, ~paste(unique(.), collapse = ", ")),
            across(everything(), paste, collapse = ", "))
result
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
# # Groups:   Site, Parent, Status [4]
#   Site  Parent Status   Country ProductProvider        ProductID               ProductName                                     
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                  <chr>                   <chr>                                           
# 1 w     W Inc. Prospect USA     Provider A, Provider B XP10, XP11, XP18, XP19  10Rockets, 11Rockets, 18Rockets, 19Rockets      
# 2 x     X Inc. Client   Canada  Provider A             XP4, XP5, XP6, XP7, XP8 4Rockets, 5Rockets, 6Rockets, 7Rockets, 8Rockets
# 3 y     Y Inc. Client   Mexico  Provider A, Provider B XP10, XP18              10Rockets, 18Rockets                            
# 4 z     Z Inc. Prospect China   Provider B             XP6                     6Rockets
```

Comment: Your solution concatenates everything except `Site`. I was just looking to concatenate the last 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet with `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(. ~ Site, df, unique)
#   Site Parent   Status Country               ProductID                                      ProductName        ProductProvider
# 1    w W Inc. Prospect     USA  XP10, XP11, XP18, XP19       10Rockets, 11Rockets, 18Rockets, 19Rockets Provider A, Provider B
# 2    x X Inc.   Client  Canada XP4, XP5, XP6, XP7, XP8 4Rockets, 5Rockets, 6Rockets, 7Rockets, 8Rockets             Provider A
# 3    y Y Inc.   Client  Mexico              XP10, XP18                             10Rockets, 18Rockets Provider A, Provider B
# 4    z Z Inc. Prospect   China                     XP6                                         6Rockets             Provider B
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! How do you remove the c("") though..

Comment: @Varun Which `c("")` do you mean?

Comment: For some reason when I try your approach, the last three columns have c("") surrounding each entry. For example, row  1, column 5 is c("XP10", "XP11", "XP18", "XP19") in my output table using your solution.

Comment: I'd prefer it without the brackets and inverted commas if possible

Comment: @Varun That's weird, are you using the up to date `R version 4.0.2`?

Comment: I'm using R ‘4.0.1’

Comment: @Varun Could still be worthwhile to update. What when you try `aggregate(. ~ Site, df, base::unique)`? Perhaps some "genius" package you've loaded overwrites the base function. Another problem is, that I create `df` on my machine and you might have a different structure than me (i.e. factors); therefore it's always better to use the output of `dput(df)` to share data where the structure is included.